# Folium/Leaflet display marker without radius?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I would like to plot a point in a Folium map. Not a circle, just a point (i.e. without a radius).

I would like for them not to zoom in if I do, but just stay as a point.

I have

```
   fmap.circle_marker(location=[row["lat"],row["lon"]], popup=row["tower"])
```

I've tried setting the `radius` to 0, and the `fill_color`/`fill_opacity` to 0 as well, but it still displays a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The folium documentation states that there is different types of markers you can use, the circle marker you are trying to implement does excactly what your'e experiencing.

Try using:

```
fmap.marker(location=[row["lat"],row["lon"]], popup=row["tower"])
```

This should print a normal dot.

Else look at [the folium documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/folium/latest/folium.pdf) under the quick start guide page 4